# Netbeans does not support Jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am developing an application in Netbeans 7.1.1, but I cannot run the app because netbeans does not recognize the JSF libraries?
[image]

[image]

Why doesn't netbeans knows where the jsf libraries, are even when they are in the properties file?

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: ohhhh thx ;) I forgot about that!

Comment: btw but why is my question -1? Is the answer soooo clear?(But I have to be honest... not to me...)

Comment: Where did you get that NetBeans doesn't support JSF? Did you copy and paste this application from somewhere?

Comment: yes I am trying that application out! Here I got that it supports jsf: http://netbeans.org/community/releases/71/

Comment: Try some sample on your own in JSF. Sometimes it may happen that if you paste code from some other application, it is not recognized (may be because of different versions) that doesn't mean that NetBeans doesn't support JSF. Did you copy this code from somewhere else?

Comment: this iks a maven project, do you have the jsf libs in your pom?

Comment: ok i solved it. I just had to add the jsf libarys. So rightclick on the project and add libarys. Btw thx to all of you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the libraries node and make sure that JSF library is listed there. If it isn't you should add it by right-clicking libraries node and choosing Add Library.